# Lastpass folder location on win7 64 Firefox 17?

Tags: firefox, lastpass

I work on Windows 7 64bit, and just download Firefox 17.0.1 and addons lastpass, but I can't find where lastpass  folder.

It's not here %AppData% and I search 'last & pass & lastpass' and find nothing the site say 'Windows Vista/7 Internet Explorer, Firefox: %AppData%..\LocalLow\LastPass\' but there is nothing there?

Comment: Why do you want to locate a local encrypted cache file?

Comment: @Ramhound, why not?

Comment: What do you expect to do with an encrypted file that is based an online account?

Comment: @Ramhound I know where it is on XP and ubuntu but I dont know where its is on 7 and I want to secure delete it before shutdown because this isn't my PC, and I don't care if its encrypted or not I just want to know where last pass cache folder

Comment: Its going to be located more then likely in the same location as the Firefox profile.  So where does the portable Firefox build store its add-on cache files?

Comment: look like no one know the answer, you may remove the question.

Comment: This website does not work like that.  Questions are not deleted because "nobody" knows the answer.  They might be closed because of lack of information required to answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

%AppData% will take you to AppData\Roaming\

Try manually navigating to the directory

C:\Users\user_name\AppData\LocalLow\LastPass

Comment: nothing, there is something I didn't mention that I use portable version of firefox, Is that make any difference?

Comment: @illsecure - That makes a huge difference.

Comment: @Ramhound, ok where I can found the folder? or whats its name to search for.

Comment: @illsecure - I have no idea where the portable version of Firefox stores its files, and furthermore, is that even supported?  Seems like you should be asking whom ever distrubutes the portable firefox build this question.